# the irq handler can be interrupt by the same irq again in single core cpu

Tags: linux, kernel, interrupt

examples: irq_A and its irq handler handler_A keep in 'top half'
in single core cpu environment, when peripheral device produce irq_A, cpu doing handler_A, if handler_A is high cpu-consumming processing and before it completed peripheral device comes another irq_A, what will cpu do, it interrupt the current running handler_A?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the IRQ is enabled during execution of its handler. Usually an IRQ is disabled during its servicing to prevent interruption of the handler by itself.